# How to copy particular files from sFTP source location if the files are not already present in sFTP sink location in Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I want to filter source folder for files have name starting with 'File'.
Then I want to check if those files are already present in sink folder.
If not present then copy else skip.

Picture 1 -This is the initial picture which contains files in source and sink
[image: This is the initial picture which contains files in source and sink]

Picture 2 - This is the desired output where only those files are copied which were not present in Sink (except junk files)
[image: This is the desired output where only those files are copied which were not present in Sink (except junk files)]

Picture 3 - This is how I tried. There are IF & copyData activity in ForEach, But I am getting error in copyData activity.
[image: This is how I tried. There are IF & copyData activity in ForEach, But I am getting error in copyData activity.]

Comment: Hi, please provide the error message you are getting in the copy activity.

Comment: Hi, Below is the error msg:
ErrorCode=UserErrorInvalidValueInPayload,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=Failed to convert the value in 'fileName' property to 'System.String' type. Please make sure the payload structure and value are correct.,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.DataContracts,''Type=System.InvalidCastException,Message=Object must implement IConvertible.,Source=mscorlib,'

Comment: Error message states, the filename which you are passing in the copy activity is not of string type. It is expecting a string-type value. If you are passing the current item of the Foreach loop, instead pass the current-item.column_name (@item().name)

Answer (score 1):

I have reproed in my local environment as shown below.

1. Get sink files list where filename starts with ‘file’ using **Get Metadata** activity.

[image]

The output of Get Metadata1:

[image]

2. Create an **array variable** to store the list of sink files.

[image]

3. Convert **Get Metadata** activity (Get sink files) output to the array by using **ForEach** activity and append each filename to an array variable.

`@activity('Get Sink Files').output.childItems`

[image]

Add **append variable** activity inside ForEach activity.

[image]

4. Now get the list of source files using another `Get Metadata` activity in the pipeline.

[image]

The output of Get metadata2:

[image]

5. Connect **Get Metadata** activity2 (Get Source files) output and ForEach activity to another ForEach activity2.

`@activity('Get Source Files').output.childItems`

[image]

6. Add **If Condition** activity inside ForEach2 activity. Add expression to check the current item (each source file) contains in the array variable.

`@contains(variables('sink_files_list'),item().name)`

[image]

7. When false add **copy activity** to copy source file to sink.

**Source**:

[image]

**Sink**:

[image]

Comment: Hey @DigiLearner, I did reproduce this issue and the solution worked for me; do let me know if it solved your problem else share more details so I can troubleshoot?